# failing hidden test, can't find flaw

Tags: python, algorithm, loops

So my instruction are as follows:

We are interested in the value of z when x and y are integers. Write a function `poly2max(a, b, c d)` that takes parameters specifying minimum and maximum values for x and y. It should return the maximum value z takes for any x and y chosen from those ranges. For example, evaluating `poly2max(0,5,3,7)` would search through values of x from 0 up to 5 (including both 0 and 5), using values of y from 3 up to 7 (including both 3 and 7) to find this polynomial function's largest value.

My code is passing every public test and almost every hidden test, but one and I can't find a flaw.

Here's my code:

```
def poly2max ( a, b, c, d ):

results = []

for x in range( a, b ):
    for y in range ( c, d ):

        z = (-x**4 + 3*x**2 - y**4 + 5*y**2)
        results.append( z )

if a == b:
    if c == d:
        x = a
        y = c
        z = (-x**4 + 3*x**2 - y**4 + 5*y**2) 
    return z

if (a, b, c, d ) == (0, 0, 0, 0):
    return 0

if a == b:
    for y in range ( c, d ):
        x = a
        z = (-x**4 + 3*x**2 - y**4 + 5*y**2)
        results.append( z )
    return max( results )

if c == d:
    for x in range( a, b ):
        y = c
        z = (-x**4 + 3*x**2 - y**4 + 5*y**2)
        results.append( z ) 
    return max( results )

else:
    return max( results )
```

Comment: `range(a, b)` goes from a (inclusive) to b (exclusive). It looks like you've hacked lots of special cases in to pass tests to work around this (since the problem requires inclusive ranges), rather than fixing the root cause.

Answer (score 2):

If you want all values from a to b including both a and b you should use range(a,b+1).

Also, your code is way more complicated than necessary. This should do it:

```
def poly2max ( a, b, c, d ):
    results = []
    for x in range( a, b+1 ):
        for y in range ( c, d+1 ):
            z = (-x**4 + 3*x**2 - y**4 + 5*y**2)
            results.append( z )
    return max( results )
```

The only problem I can see here is if b < a or d < c, but it seems you are guaranteed that's not the case, and besides, it's easy to check that in the beginning.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! This makes so much sense.